# Can I Use Facebook Graph API to Read My Facebook Page Fans' Walls?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am wondering if there is a way to programmatically read the wall posts of my Facebook Page's fans (I mean those who "like" my Facebook Page) by either using Graph API or FQL.

I would like to develop an application that aggregates my fans' wall posts so that I can get to know what kind of people "like" my Facebook Page by reading what they are saying in their walls.

Comment: Now I'm confused! Your title and first portion of your question is talking about *reading* posts from **your** FB page wall. And in the last sentence you are talking about *reading* posts from the **fans** walls!

Comment: Sorry to confuse you, but I mentioned "read the wall posts of my Facebook Page's *fans*".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't get this level of access just for having had someone like your page. You would need to specifically request access using a Facebook application.

Comment: Hi, thanks for such a quick answer! You just saved a lot of my time. :)

Comment: how to enumerate posts that are made public? for eg. even without logging into fb, you can see posts in fb.com/pepsi page how can I retrieve it?